# Making Wordpress.com portfolio responsive

Tags: css, wordpress, responsiveness

I am working on this Wordpress.com site: www.theslowmelt.com. The homepage portfolio is great, but the portfolios for the two Makers Series pages aren't responsive:
https://theslowmelt.com/portfolio/makers-series/;
https://theslowmelt.com/makers-series/

I have had to add a lot of code to the CSS to change the font size and featured image sizes and make these pages full-width, and I believe these things are interfering with the responsiveness, but I still want these portfolios to look exactly the same as the homepage portfolio. And I want them to respond the same way the homepage portfolio does.

I've chatted with a Wordpress rep about this and worked on the pages with my friend, who is a developer. The Wordpress rep said this: "It looks like you're using the portfolio shortcode on those pages and the same CSS isn't being applied." He suggested I reach out to the Wordpress community. My developer friend found out that these parts of the custom CSS (BELOW; LINE 112 AND LINES 125-129) are what are preventing the page from being responsive; however, taking away these lines make the images different sizes AND make it so the portfolio isn't full-width anymore.

```
.postid-382 .column-3 .portfolio-entry {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    width: 349px; JUST THIS LINE - LINE 112
    margin-right: 22px;
}

ALL OF THIS BELOW - LINES 125-129
.postid-382 .portfolio-featured-image img {
    height: 262px;
    width: 360px;
}
```

Could anyone help me make these two portfolios responsive? Thank you so much, in advance, for your help!

Comment: those pages seem to scale OK for me on mobile. what's wrong with them?

Comment: Hi, Michael. Thank you so much for your response. I'm sorry it's taken me so long to get back to you. The images are okay on mobile (some of them are slightly stretched, but that's all right), but it's really when I look at it on a tablet. There should still be three images across, just like the homepage looks on a tablet. Instead, there are two and then one and then two images. The same thing happens when I resize my browser on my laptop and desktop.

Comment: Try removing `width` from `.postid-382 .column-3 .portfolio-entry` and change it to `max-width` instead so it's `.postid-382 .column-3 .portfolio-entry { max-width: 349px; }`, then add `@media (max-width: 800px) { .postid-382 .column-3 .portfolio-entry { max-width: 100%; } }` Also remove `.postid-382 .portfolio-featured-image img {
    height: 262px;
    width: 360px;
}` and the images won't stretch, but you might need to resize some of your images.